# trouble with getting RegExp to work

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use Regular expressions in javascript and I just cannot get anything to work for example

```
        var pattern = new RegExp('http');
        var hi = "http://hi.m3u8";
        console.log(hi.indexOf(pattern));
```

this is returning -1? even though there is definitely an http in the variable hi so? any idea on what I might be donig wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When using `regex` you should use `match` or `test` and not `indexOf`, but in your case it doesn't make sense to use regex. Using `indexOf` is good enough:

```js
var pattern = 'http';
var hi = "http://hi.m3u8";
console.log(hi.indexOf(pattern));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are tested like this

```js
    var pattern = new RegExp('http');
        var hi = "http://hi.m3u8";
        console.log(pattern.test(hi));
```